# Inequality with even powers of trigonometric functions

Tags: inequalities, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

For $m>0$,
 $0 < n\leqslant m+1$  ($m,n\in \mathbb{Z} $) ,   and $0 < a < 1$ , prove that
$$2^{n}\cdot \left( a^{n}\cos ^{2m}\dfrac {\pi a} {2}+\left( 1-a\right) ^{n}\sin ^{2m}\dfrac {\pi a} {2}\right) \leqslant\cos ^{2m}\dfrac {\pi a} {2}+\sin ^{2m}\dfrac {\pi a} {2}. $$

Comment: Can you give some context for this?

Comment: Seconding Douglas's request

Answer (score 4):

Note that both sides are equal at $a=1/2$, and symmetric under $a \to 1-a$.
So let's assume $0 < a < 1/2$.  Then the
 inequality says $$\tan^{2m}(\pi a/2) \le \dfrac{1 - 2^n a^n}{2^n (1-a)^n - 1}$$
Now in fact, since $\tan$ is convex on $[0,\pi/4]$ we have $\tan^{2m}(\pi a/2) \le (2a)^{2m}$, and it suffices to prove that
$$ 2^{2n-1} a^{2n-1} \le \dfrac{1 - 2^n a^n}{2^n (1-a)^n - 1}$$ 
i.e. that $2^{3n-1}a^{2n-1} (1-a)^n \le 1 - 2^n a^n + 2^{2n-1} a^{2n-1}$.
In fact, $a(1-a) \le 1/4$, so
$2^{3n-1} a^{2n-1}(1-a)^n \le 2^{n-1} a^{n-1}$,
and $(1-2^n a^n)(1-2^{n-1}a^{n-1}) \ge 0$ so
$2^{n-1} a^{n-1} \le 1 - 2^n a^n + 2^{2n-1} a^{2n-1}$.